# solve an irrational equation $1+\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{|x|}=(x^2+x)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As the title, I want to solve this equation: $$1+\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{|x|}=(x^2+x)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})$$
Any help would be appreciated

I have tried to transform it to the something like $$1+\sqrt{x^2+x+3}=1+\sqrt{2x+3}$$ then $$x^2+x=2x$$
But this equation is not easy to transform it to that form

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JC12 I have tried to transform the equation to make both sides have the same form, then I use derivative, but it doesn't work very well. I also try other ways but it also deadlock

Answer (score 3):

An a way is:$$1+\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{|x|}=(x^2+x-1+1)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})$$
$$1+\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{|x|}=(x^2+x-1)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})+1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}$$
$$\sqrt{2x^2+1}-|x|\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}=|x|(x^2+x-1)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})$$
If $x>0$

$$\sqrt{2x^2+1}-x\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}=x(x^2+x-1)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})$$
$$\frac{-x^4 - 2 x^3 - x^2 +1}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}+x\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}=x(x^2+x-1)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})$$
$$\frac{-(x^2 + x - 1) (x^2 + x + 1)}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}+x\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}=x(x^2+x-1)(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})$$
$$(x^2+x-1)\left(\frac{- (x^2 + x + 1)}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}+x\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}-x(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})\right)=0$$

$$(x^2+x-1)\left(\frac{(x^2 + x + 1)}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}+x\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}+x(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})\right)=0$$
How $x>0$   the second factor is always positive, then the only solution is when:
$$x^2+x-1=0\implies x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

If $x<0$ then:
$$(x^2+x-1)\left(\frac{-(x^2 + x + 1)}{\sqrt{2x^2+1}-x\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}+x(1+\sqrt{x^2+2x+3})\right)=0$$
The second factor is always negative, Therefore in this case is the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing both sides of the equation:

[image]

Comment: this is a visualization, do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: Some aproximation method.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is just a nightmare since using multiple squarings, we end with a polynomial of degree $13$ in $x$.

However, looking at the plot given by @Aqua, it is "obvious" that the roots are $x=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)$ and $x=-\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)$ (think about the golden ratio to make the answer nicer).

Comment: what do you mean by golden ratio, I still don't get it

Comment: @Becker https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio

Comment: I mean the relationship between golden ratio and the solution of the equation

Comment: @Becker. What are the numbers I gave ?